# Django ModelSelect2Widget ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "Inv_Item.mar" must be a "Inv_Marca" instance

Tags: python, django

Tengo un formulario ITEM(inventario), dentro de esta existen varias relaciones que las muestro en un ModelSelect2Widget. Al momento de que hace un form.save me da el siguiente error:

```
Internal Server Error: /552/item/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\app\appls\inv_man\views\vw_inv_item.py", line 96, in post
    print(form.is_valid())
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 170, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 408, in _post_clean
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 63, in construct_instance
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.name, data)
  File "C:\Users\Dre\PycharmProjects\erpuda\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "Inv_Item.mar" must be a "Inv_Marca" instance.
[22/Mar/2022 10:48:04] "POST /552/item/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121009
```

El forms.py de item es:

```
class Inv_ItemForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Obtiene la variable de sesion desde la vista y la asigna al self
        self.AIGN_EMP_ID = kwargs.pop("AIGN_EMP_ID")
        self.AIGN_PER_ID = kwargs.pop("AIGN_PER_ID")
        # Control de roles
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.AIGN_OPCIONES = kwargs.pop("AIGN_OPCIONES")
        self.PERMISOS = []  # para recuperar los permisos de la tabla
        __json_values = json.loads(json.dumps(self.AIGN_OPCIONES))
        self.PERMISOS = recuperarPermisos(__json_values, self._meta.model.get_table_name(self._meta.model))
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        super(Inv_ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Cambiar atributos especificos
        self.fields['tit_id'] = ModelChoiceField(label='Tipo item', queryset=self.get_choicesTit(),
                                                     widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                         search_fields=['tit_nombre__icontains',
                                                                        'tit_codigov__icontains'],
                                                         # dependent_fields={'tit_codigov': 'tit_codigov'},
                                                         attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                                'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                                'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                         # to_field_name="cue_codigov"
                                                     ), required=True)

        self.fields['mod_id'] = ModelChoiceField(label='Modelo', queryset=self.get_choicesMod(),
                                              widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                  search_fields=['mod_nombre__icontains'],
                                                  # dependent_fields={'tit_codigov': 'tit_codigov'},
                                                  attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                         'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                         'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                  # to_field_name="cue_codigov"
                                              ), required=True)

        self.fields['mar'] = ModelChoiceField(label='Marca', queryset=self.get_choicesMar(),
                                              widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                  search_fields=['mar_nombre__icontains',
                                                                 'mar_codigov__icontains'],
                                                  dependent_fields={'mar_codigov': 'mar_codigov'},
                                                  attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                         'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                         'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                  model=Inv_Marca,
                                                  to_field_name="mar_codigov",
                                              ), required=True)


        self.fields['lin_id'] = ModelChoiceField(label='Linea', queryset=self.get_choicesLin(),
                                              widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                  search_fields=['lin_nombre__icontains',
                                                                 'lin_codigov__icontains'],
                                                  # dependent_fields={'tit_codigov': 'tit_codigov'},
                                                  attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                         'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                         'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                  # to_field_name="cue_codigov"
                                              ), required=True)
        self.fields['ume_id'] = ModelChoiceField(label='Unidad de medida', queryset=self.get_choicesUme(),
                                              widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                  search_fields=['ume_nombre__icontains',
                                                                 'ume_codigov__icontains'],
                                                  # dependent_fields={'tit_codigov': 'tit_codigov'},
                                                  attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                         'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                         'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                  # to_field_name="cue_codigov"
                                              ), required=True)
        # Cambiar atributos especificos
        self.fields['tid_codigov_ice'] = ModelChoiceField(label='ICE', queryset=self.get_choicesICE(),
                                              widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                                                  search_fields=['tid_descripcion__icontains',
                                                                 'tid_codigov__icontains'],
                                                  # dependent_fields={'tit_codigov': 'tit_codigov'},
                                                  attrs={"data-placeholder": '--------',
                                                         'data-minimum-input-length': 0,
                                                         'style': 'width: 120%;'},
                                                  # to_field_name="cue_codigov"
                                              ), required=False)
        # Cambiar atributos genericos
        for form in self.visible_fields():
            form.field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = Form_CSS.fields_placeholder + form.field.label.lower()
            form.field.widget.attrs['autocomplete'] = Form_CSS.fields_autocomplete
            form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = Form_CSS.fields_attr_class
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        attr = Form_CSS.form_attrs
        attr['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data'
        self.helper.attrs = attr
        self.helper.form_id = Form_CSS.getFormID(self)
        # self.helper.attrs = Form_CSS.form_attrs
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_error_title = Form_CSS.form_err_title
        self.helper.form_class = Form_CSS.form_class
        self.helper.label_class = Form_CSS.fields_label_class
        self.helper.field_class = Form_CSS.fields_field_class
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                DivHeaderWithButtons(instance_pk=self.instance.pk, permisos=self.PERMISOS),
                Div(
                    Div(
                        Div('ite_codigov',
                            'ite_codigob',
                            'ite_nombre',
                            'tit_id',
                            'mod_id',
                            'mar',
                            'lin_id',
                            'ume_id',
                            'ite_cantmin',
                            'ite_cantmax',
                            'ite_costopro',
                            css_class='col-sm'),
                        Div(
                            'ite_esactivo',
                            'ite_esventa',
                            'tig_codigov_iva',
                            'ite_tipo',
                            'tid_codigov_ice',
                            'ite_ice_val',
                            'ite_irbp_val',
                            'ite_img',
                            'emp_id',
                            css_class='col-sm'),
                        css_class='row'
                    ),
                    css_class='card-body', id='body_id'
                ),
                css_class='card'
            ),
            Div(
                TabHolder(
                    Tab(
                        'Unidades de medida secundarias',
                        DivGridHeaderWithButtons(instance_pk=self.instance.pk, grid_opts=get_invUnidadMedidaDetsForm(None,self.AIGN_EMP_ID)),
                    ),
                    Tab(
                        'Información de ítem',
                        DivGridHeaderWithButtons(instance_pk=self.instance.pk, grid_opts=get_invCampoitemDetsForm(None,self.AIGN_EMP_ID)),
                    ),
                    Tab(
                        'Contabilización',
                        DivGridHeaderWithButtons(instance_pk=self.instance.pk, grid_opts=get_invCuentaItemDetsForm(None,self.AIGN_EMP_ID, self.AIGN_PER_ID)),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
    class Meta:
        imp_grupo = Imp_TipoImpuestoGrupo.objects.filter(tig_estado=1).order_by('tig_orden')
        model = Inv_Item
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['ite_estado']
        widgets = {
            'emp_id': HiddenInput(),
            'ite_tipo': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'tig_codigov_iva': forms.RadioSelect(choices=((x.tig_id, x.tig_codigov +': '+ x.tig_nombre) for x in imp_grupo)),
        }

    # Método para mostrar errores de validaciones personalizadas
    def clean(self):
        form_data = self.data
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # *** Validación del codigov ***
        if (self.instance.pk is None):
            codRep = Inv_Item.countRegister(Inv_Item, 'ite_codigov', form_data['ite_codigov'], 'ite_estado')[0]
        else:
            codRep = Inv_Item.countRegister(Inv_Item, 'ite_codigov', form_data['ite_codigov'],
                                                             'ite_estado', 'ite_id', self.instance.pk)[0]
        if (codRep > 0):
            self._errors['ite_codigov'] = [CRUD_MSG.CODIGOV_DUPLICADO]
            del form_data['ite_codigov']
        return form_data

    def get_choicesTit(self):
        return Inv_Tipoitem.objects.filter(tit_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by('tit_codigov')

    def get_choicesMod(self):
        return Inv_Modelo.objects.filter(mod_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by('mod_nombre')

    def get_choicesMar(self):
        return Inv_Marca.objects.filter(mar_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by('mar_codigov')

    def get_choicesLin(self):
        return Inv_Linea.objects.filter(lin_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by('lin_codigov')

    def get_choicesUme(self):
        return Inv_Unidadmedida.objects.filter(ume_estado=1, emp_id=self.AIGN_EMP_ID).order_by('ume_codigov')

    def get_choicesICE(self):
        return Imp_TipoImpuestoDetalle.objects.select_related('tim').filter(tid_estado=1, tim__tim_estado=1, tim__tim_codigov= 'ICE').order_by('tid_codigov')
```

El modelo es:

```
class Inv_Item(ERPBaseModel):
    class Choices_InvTipo(models.IntegerChoices):
        Bien = 1, _('Bienes')
        Serv = 0, _('Servicios')

    ite_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='id')
    ite_codigov = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='Código')
    ite_codigob = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Código de barras')
    ite_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Nombre')
    ite_cantmin = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99999)],verbose_name='Cantidad minima')
    ite_cantmax = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99999)],verbose_name='Cantidad maxima')
    ite_tipo = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=Choices_InvTipo.choices, default=Choices_InvTipo.Bien, verbose_name='Tipo')
    ite_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Imagen')
    tig_codigov_iva = models.CharField(default=1, max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='IVA')
    tid_codigov_ice = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='ICE')
    ite_ice_val = models.DecimalField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Valor ICE')
    ite_irbp_val = models.DecimalField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Valor IRBP')
    ite_costopro = models.DecimalField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)], max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, verbose_name='Costo producto')
    ite_esactivo = models.BooleanField(default=1, verbose_name='Activo')
    ite_esventa = models.BooleanField(default=1, verbose_name='Venta')
    mar = models.ForeignKey(Inv_Marca, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Marca')
    mod_id = models.ForeignKey(Inv_Modelo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='mod_id', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Modelo')
    tit_id = models.ForeignKey(Inv_Tipoitem, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tit_id', verbose_name='Tipo item')
    ume_id = models.ForeignKey(Inv_Unidadmedida, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ume_id', verbose_name='Unidad de medida')
    lin_id = models.ForeignKey(Inv_Linea, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='lin_id', verbose_name='Linea')
    emp_id = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Empresa')
    ite_estado = models.SmallIntegerField(default=True, verbose_name='Estado')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'inv\".\"item'
        unique_together = (('ite_id', 'emp_id'), ('ite_codigov', 'emp_id'))
        verbose_name = 'Ítem'
        verbose_name_plural = "Ítems"
```

Y la vista es:

```
class Inv_ItemCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Inv_Item
    form_class = Inv_ItemForm
    template_name = 'inv_item/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inv_man:inv_item_list')
    error_url = reverse_lazy('imp_man:inv_item_add')

    # Asigna al kwargs la variable de session desde el formulario
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(Inv_ItemCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_EMP_ID': self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID')})
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_PER_ID': self.request.session.get('AIGN_PER_ID')})
        # Roles
        kwargs.update({'AIGN_OPCIONES': self.request.session['AIGN_OPCIONES']})
        return kwargs

    # Inicializar el formulario
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'emp_id': self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID'),
                'per_id': self.request.session.get('AIGN_PER_ID')}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        emp = self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID')
        per = self.request.session.get('AIGN_PER_ID')
        r = {'a': 1}
        form = self.get_form()
        extra_errors = []
        request.POST._mutable = True

        print(form.is_valid())
        print(form._errors)
        if 'CREATE' in request.POST:
            print(form)
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    # -------------------------------------------------------------
                    data_grid_unidadMedida = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(request.POST['unidadMedida_grid']))
                    data_grid_camposItem = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(request.POST['camposItem_grid']))
                    data_grid_cuentaItem = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(request.POST['cuentaitem_grid']))
                    with transaction.atomic():

                        # --- Valida que el codigov del detalle secuencial transacción no se repita ---
                        for index, row in data_grid_unidadMedida.iterrows():
                            for index1, row1 in data_grid_unidadMedida.iterrows():
                                if (index != index1):
                                    if (row.ume_id_secundaria_id == row1.ume_id_secundaria_id):
                                        error_msg = 'Unidad de medida: ' + str(
                                            CRUD_MSG.CODIGOV_DUPLICADO_DET) + ': ' + str(row1.ume_id_secundaria_id)
                                        extra_errors.append(error_msg)
                                        return JsonResponse({'__all__': extra_errors})

                        # Guarda cabecera y detalle
                        cabecera = form.save(commit=False)
                        print('llego 2')
                        cabecera.save()
                        for index, row in data_grid_unidadMedida.iterrows():
                            iteUme = Inv_ItemUnidadMedida()
                            iteUme.ume_id_secundaria_id = row.ume_id_secundaria_id
                            iteUme.umd_cant_secundaria = float(row.umd_cant_secundaria)
                            iteUme.ite_id = cabecera.pk
                            iteUme.emp_id = emp
                            iteUme.save()
                        for index, row in data_grid_camposItem.iterrows():
                            ici = Inv_ItemCampoitem()
                            ici.ite_id = cabecera.pk
                            ici.cit_id = row.cit_id
                            ici.ici_desc = row.ici_desc
                            ici.emp_id = emp
                            ici.save()
                        for index, row in data_grid_cuentaItem.iterrows():
                            iteCue = Inv_ItemCuenta()
                            iteCue.ite_id = cabecera.pk
                            iteCue.cca_id = row.cca_id
                            iteCue.cue_id = row.cue_id
                            iteCue.per_id = per
                            iteCue.emp_id = emp
                            iteCue.save()
                        # -------------------------------------------------------------
                        messages.success(request, CRUD_MSG.CREATE)
                        return JsonResponse(r)

                except django.db.models.query_utils.InvalidQuery as e:
                    extra_errors.append(str(e))
        self.object = None
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = form
        print(dict(form._errors.items()))
        return JsonResponse(dict(form._errors.items()))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = self.model._meta.verbose_name
        context['url_list'] = self.success_url
        context['readOnly'] = {'on': 0}
        ret = []
        ret.append(get_invUnidadMedidaDetsForm(None,self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID')).to_JSON())
        ret.append(get_invCampoitemDetsForm(None,self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID')).to_JSON())
        ret.append(get_invCuentaItemDetsForm(None,self.request.session.get('AIGN_EMP_ID'),self.request.session.get('AIGN_PER_ID')).to_JSON())
        context['grids_detalles'] = ret
        return context
```

Algo curioso, es que el campo emp_id igual es una relación (que sí está reflejada en la BD, uso postgres) pero Django le toma como BigInteger y al momento de cambiarle a ForeignKey me da el mismo error mencionado anteriormente.
He cambiado la forma en como se obtiene los choices, he quitado el ModelSelect2Widget pero no parece solucionar nada. Estaba planeando modificar el tipo de dato en el modelo poniendo las relaciones como BigIntegerField, pero no estoy seguro de que tan buena práctica sea.